# Cant click on a button using the puppeteer library

Tags: javascript, button, error-handling, click, puppeteer

I have this code right here that uses the puppeteer library, I am trying to go to a website then click a button, but it's not working because it's giving me an error saying "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined" so anyone that understands puppeteer help would be appreciated.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const GAME_LINK = 'https://www.youtube.com/';

const bots = {

  browsers: [],
  pages: [],

  initialize: async () => {

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      bots.browsers.push(await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, 
        args:['--start-maximized']
      
      }));
    }


    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      bots.pages.push(await bots.browsers[0].newPage())
    }


    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      bots.pages[i].goto(GAME_LINK, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    }


    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      await bots.pages[i].setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
    }
  },

  spawn: async () => {
    
    let playButton = await bots.pages[1].$x('//button[contains(text(), "Search")]');

    await playButton[0].click();

  }
}


module.exports = bots;
```

Comment: What shows up if you try to 'display' the content of playButton[0] ? does it have events/methods? its not clear from your example what the 'problem' is

Comment: I  fixed it, the button didnt exist when i tried to access it, now i used {waitUntil:'domcontentloaded'} and it worked